# Using cosmonaut library to get a cosmosdb document by id its not working

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following objects on cosmosdb

[image]

And my code with cosmonaut library its like this:

```
 var pageTemplate = await pageTemplateStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

where id its either 0 or 1, but I am always getting null as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't decorated your object's `Id` field with `[JsonProperty("id")]` so the built in LINQ to SQL translator can't convert it. It can be found in [Cosmonaut's documentation](https://cosmonaut.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Preparing-your-classes-for-the-CosmosStore.html#jsonproperty-id)

However you should not query for documents using their id. This will perform a query instead of a read an it will cost way more RUs and more time. Use the `FindAsync` method instead which will do a direct read and will only cost 1RU.

Comment: its the FindAsync recent, because in the version I had of cosmonaut I dont find it

Comment: Which version are you using? I highly recommend you move to latest `2.8.2` as it has a lot of bug fixes and features.

Comment: the problem its that my project is using OfficePnp Core Dlls which are not compatible with asp.net core, so I downloaded your library  and added it to my solution, If I remember well more than 6 months ago, and I had to make a few changes to make it compile, I wish there were a .net framework version via nuget, that would make things a lot easier :), but your library its awesome, btw I have another question, should I decorate all fields with JsonProperty?

Comment: No it's only the id. The reason why that happens is because Cosmonaut converts the uppercase `Id` field to `id` in order to use it as the system id of the document but it can't do the same for queries so that's why you need to explicitly specify it. It only affect the id field. Btw Cosmonaut is compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1+ as it's targeting .NET Standard 1.6.

Comment: hey cool, last time I tried, I have weird issues when adding the nuget package, but this time its working fine, u coming to the summit?

Comment: Yeah I do. Ping me on twitter if you wanna meet up :)